# Sql/ VB.net - Invalid Operation Exception

Tags: sql, vb.net, exception, oledb, type-mismatch

The is a database driven currency converter, where the program has to fetch the exchange rates from the database and display them. I created the database using Microsoft Access all the data types are set to "Currency" except the Date field where it is "Date/Time".

This is what I've done so far.

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 1 USD,EUR,GBP FROM dbexchangeRates WHERE Date='" & DateTimePicker1.Text.ToString & "'"

    Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
      command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection),
      adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

        connection.Open()

        adapter.Fill(ds, "rates")

        connection.Close()

    End Using
```

This "An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression." shows up when i run. 
I was told to run data validation but I'm unsure what validations I'm suppose to use.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that `DateTimePicker1.Text.ToString` is not returning a valid date, and this is making the query fail.  Possible causes:

- **It is not a date (I'm assuming the picker enforces a date value, but still there could be an empty value or something).** In this case, you would need to alter `DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged` to handle this case and not call that query.
- **The date format from Excel doesn't match what Access expects.**  In this case, you could change the format of the date in either Excel or Access (you can find lots of help about this in other questions, etc.).

To figure this out, use the debugger or a simple print statement to view the contents of `sql`.

The problem may be obvious when you see it; if not, you can also try manually running that sql statement in Access and see what happens.